# Close activities which are running in background

Tags: android, android-activity

i have design an application where it have many activities and one activity is called from broadcast receiver and running, how to close the activities which are running related to the application or how to close other activity using new activity of the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last i find the solution it is simple **set flag**

```
Intent i1 = new Intent(context, Your class name);  
i1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // <= USE THIS
startActivity(i1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Permissions:

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

Code

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(100);
for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo taskInformation : taskInfo) {
    if (yourApplicationPackageName.equalsIgnoreCase(taskInformation.baseActivity.getClassName())) {
        String pack = taskInformation.baseActivity.getClassName().substring(0, taskInformation.baseActivity.getClassName().lastIndexOf("."));
        am.killBackgroundProcesses(pack);
    }
}
```